# Code works on 64 bit iPhone but not any others... why not?

Tags: ios, objective-c, algorithm

After experimentation, I came to realize that this code only works on 64-bit iPhones, and not on others. Not on iPads, not on my own device (iPhone 5) and not on any thing that's not specified as 64-bit. Why is this so?

```
- (void)loadVenues {
    NSString *latLon = @"30, -120";
    NSString *clientID = kCLIENTID;
    NSString *clientSecret = kCLIENTSECRET;


    NSDictionary *queryParams = @{@"ll" : latLon,
                                  @"client_id" : clientID,
                                  @"client_secret" : clientSecret,
                                  @"categoryId" : @"4bf58dd8d48988d1e0931735",
                                  @"v" : @"20140118"};

    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] getObjectsAtPath:@"/v2/venues/search"
                                           parameters:queryParams
                                              success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) 
    {
        _venues = mappingResult.array;

        NSMutableArray *temp = [(NSArray*)_venues mutableCopy];
        Venue *holder;
        for (int i = 0; i < _venues.count; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                if (((Venue *) [temp objectAtIndex:i]).location.distance < ((Venue *) [temp objectAtIndex:j]).location.distance) {
                    holder = [temp objectAtIndex:j];
                    [temp replaceObjectAtIndex:j withObject:[temp objectAtIndex:i]];
                    [temp replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:holder];
                }
            }
        }

        _venues = temp;
        [self.tableView reloadData];

    } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"What do you mean by 'there is no coffee?': %@", error);
    }];
}
```

Comment: Exactly what isn't working about it? An exception, logic error?

Comment: You don't "sort an algorithm", you use a "sorting algorithm"

Comment: @theMonster I'm not getting any exception errors, it just seems that the array isn't loading in the correct order that it should be. It seems as it is loaded in a random sequence.

Comment: So it's correctly getting rid/replacing of the data you don't want. But the sorting on that array is not what you want? Also, what is the objective of your sorting algorithm? I'm guessing it's to find the closest venue? Or is it to sort the Venues by distance?

Comment: @theMonster It's not sorting it at all. However, the array is manipulated by the for loop, just not in the way I intend it to be manipulated.

Comment: Well what's the intended outcome?

Comment: @theMonster After more investigation, I realized the code works with the 64-bit iPhone simulator, but not on my device (iPhone 5) or the iPhone 4 non 64-bit. Any ideas as to why?

Comment: Why are you casting a mutable copy to an nsarray, and then assigning that to an nsmutablearray? `NSMutableArray *temp = [(NSArray*)_venues mutableCopy];`

Comment: Because _venues is an NSArray and I can't manipulate that one as easily. @doctordoder

Comment: Ya, I can think of a couple. The one on the forefront of my mind is that `.distance` property. What's it's type / how is it defined?

Comment: @theMonster its of type NSNumber, and is defined after pulling JSON data from an API

Answer (score 0):

Not that I think your sorting algorithm is bunk, but why don't you simplify your code by using the built in sorting algorithms?

```
NSMutableArray *arrayToSort = (NSMutableArray *)mappingResult.array;
[arrayToSort sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
    Venue *venue1 = obj1;
    Venue *venue2 = obj2;
    double value1 = venue1.location.distance;
    double value2 = venue2.location.distance;
    if (value1 > value2)
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    else if (value1 < value2)
        return NSOrderedDescending;
    else
        return NSOrderedSame;
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I know what the problem is. You said that .distance is of type `NSNumber`. So what you're doing is comparing two objects. What you want is to compare two float values. So you should revise your if statement code to this:

```
if (((Venue *) [temp objectAtIndex:i]).location.distance.floatValue < ((Venue *) [temp objectAtIndex:j]).location.distance.floatValue)
```

I also suggest that you use @doctordoder's revision

Comment: sweet, thank you! Why don't 32-bit iphones support this?

Comment: It is supported, I'm not sure why you think it isn't. But if this is the right answer, it would be great if you accepted it as such :).